# Is possible to stop application in VMware vFabric server using java code

Tags: jsf, web-applications, vmware

I am using `vfabric-tc-server-standard-2.8.1`.
I created instance "project" in vFabric like:

```
C:/../../vfabric-tc-server-standard-2.8.1/project/
```

I have created two web applications "Demo1" and "Demo2".
I deployed both "Demo1.war" & "Demo2.war" into that project:

```
C:/../../vfabric-tc-server-standard-2.8.1/project/webapps/Demo1.war
C:/../../vfabric-tc-server-standard-2.8.1/project/webapps/Demo2.war
```

My "Demo2" project has a simple JSP page. That page contains 2 buttons "Stop Demo1 Apps" and "Start Demo1 Apps".

I need to stop "Demo1" application, when I press "Stop Demo1 Apps".
I need to start "Demo1" application, when I press "Start Demo1 Apps".
Is possible to start and stop the specific application in vFabric using Java code?

Comment: I think you need to edit your post... It's confusing in the `That page contains 2 buttons "Start Demo1 Apps" and "Start Demo1 Apps".` and `Then
I need to stop Demo1 application, when i press "Start Demo1 Apps"`

Comment: @JScoobyCed Thanks for your support. Now i editied my question. Do you have any idea about "vFabric"?